# How to fetch only condition satisfied/match object from an array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB.

This is my 'masterpatients' collection it has many documents. every documents contain 'visits' array and every visits array contains multiple objects. I want only those object which is satisfied with my input.
I am expecting only below the expected output. if the facility match with my input and visit date range match with my provided input then the query should return only that object as I have given below.

```
_id:5ef59134a3d8d92e580510fe
    flag:0
    name:"emicon_test"
    dob:2020-06-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
    visits:[
     {
        visit:2020-06-09T10:36:10.635+00:00,
        facility:"Atria Lady Lake"
     },
    { 
       visit:2020-05-09T10:36:10.635+00:00,
       facility:"demo"
    }]
    
    _id:5ee3213040f8830e04ff74a8
    flag:0
    name:"xyz"
    dob:1995-06-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
    visits:[
     {
        visit:2020-05-01T10:36:10.635+00:00,
        facility:"pqr"
        
     },
    {
       visit:2020-05-15T10:36:10.635+00:00,
       facility:"demo"
       
    },
    {  
       visit:2020-05-09T10:36:10.635+00:00,
       facility:"efg"
    }]
```

My query input parameters is facility='demo' and visit date range is from '1st May 2020' to '10th May 2020'

output expected:

```
_id:5ef59134a3d8d92e580510fe
    flag:0
    name:"emicon_test"
    dob:2020-06-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
    visits:[
    { 
       visit:2020-05-09T10:36:10.635+00:00,
       facility:"demo"
    }]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection)

Comment: @Joe yes but it returns a whole array, not a specific object as I mention output.

Comment: what filters did you use in the elemMatch?

Comment: Joe I have used $gte and $lte filter

Comment: can you edit that query into the question

Comment: Also take a look at the example at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#zipcode-search, that seems to be exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer.

```
MasterPatientModel.aggregate([
                {
                    '$unwind':"$visits"
                },
                {"$match": {"visits.visit": {"$gte": new Date(req.body.facilitySummaryFromdate), "$lte": new Date(req.body.facilitySummaryTodate)
                                            } ,  "visits.facility":  req.body.facilitySummary
                           }
                }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter the contents of a mongo collection property on the server.

Make visits array into a top level collection/model and you can filter by criteria on the server.